# Are functions under which preimage of recursive sets are recursive sets always recursive?

Tags: logic, recursion, computability

It is well known that preimage of a recursive set under a recursive function is a recursive set (see for example [Image and preimage of a recursive function on a recursive set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2310493/image-and-preimage-of-a-recursive-function-on-a-recursive-set)).

I wonder whether some converse is true:

Assume the preimage of every recursive set under a given function from $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb N^k$ is a recursive set.

Is this function necessarily recursive ?

Comment: This is a great question, but it has in fact been answered here before: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4172930/are-all-continuous-functions-computable-for-a-peculiar-definition-of-continuity/4173005#4173005. Although the question there is different ("recursively enumerable" in place of "recursive"), my answer applies to this question too. (And actually even that difference is insignificant since the complement of the preimage is the preimage of the complement.)